# Ionic 3 Cannot find module "sha256"

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm having this error and this error only on Ionic 3.2. This is my ionic info.

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.0.0
Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI        : 3.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.0.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.0.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.1.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.0
```

Comment: By providing [mcve], let me know,  where you are importing the module and where you are using `sha256`, so I can help.

Comment: @rmalviya I figured it out using this thread https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-i-use-sha256-function-in-ionic-2/69418/9

Comment: Great. [so] community always suggest to first [google](http://www.google.com/) the problem. :-)